# Set default value to ipywidgets - Python

Tags: python, widget, ipywidgets

I am creating a `BoundedIntText` widget using `ipywidgets` with the following code:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

mywidget = widgets.BoundedIntText(min=0, max=100, step=1, description='CC (%):', disabled=False)
```

Nothign wrong with that, but when displaying it, the default value is 0 (or whatever `min` value I set).

```
display(mywidget)
mywidget.value
```

[image]

My question is, how can I make so that the when displaying the widget, the default value until a user introduces an input is `None` (or something different that 0)?

Comment: it should be as simple as setting the `value` parameter. See [this](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#BoundedIntText)

Comment: @Ma0 Could you please provide an example of it?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#BoundedIntText), you can do this by setting the `value` parameter to whatever you want your initial value to be.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

mywidget = widgets.BoundedIntText(value=1, min=0, max=100, step=1, description='CC (%):', disabled=False)
```

That being said, I am not sure whether you can leave it blank or have it display `None` (I do not have `ipywidgets` installed and can therefore not test it).

Comment: I do not think that this is possible. If you just want to make sure that the user has set this parameter, expand the range to, say, include -1, make that the default value and treat is as invalid input.